# Cakephp-upload plugin not saving images

Tags: php, cakephp, upload

I am trying to upload images and save them using cakephp-upload plugin 2.0 (latest version to date). This is my database table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'photos' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'image' varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  'imgpath' varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  'album_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'created' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  'modified' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  KEY 'idx_album_id' ('album_id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And here's the model file. (Photo.php)

```
 public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'image' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'dir' => 'imgpath'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Finally, this is my view.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Photo'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Photo'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file'));
        echo $this->Form->input('imgpath');
        echo $this->Form->input('album_id');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

I have read given [instructions](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload#readme) but still images do not save to webroot/files/...
I am using cakephp 2.4.7 and php 5.4 in windows 7. I have not installed Imagick since WAMP 2.2 has GD2 enabled.

What more should I do to make this work?

Comment: add type on form create. `$this->Form->create('Photo', array('type' => 'file'));` and echo $this->Form->input('imgpath', array('type' => 'hidden'));

Comment: @FazalRasel thank you so much now image gets saved in folder but why my database imgpath does not get the path that image got saved??? And if you can put above comment as a answer I will accept it as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating comments to make this answer officially---

Change 
`echo $this->Form->create('Photo');` to `echo $this->Form->create('Photo', array('type' => 'file'));`

And

`echo $this->Form->input('imgpath');` to `echo $this->Form->input('imgpath', array('type' => 'hidden'));`

Comment: Do you know why imgpath does not get saved?

Comment: could you please provide me more details... Mean place `debug($this->data)` on `Photo.php` models `beforeSave()` and let me know the details...

Comment: It seems that it is empty. But except for imgpath other information gets saved!

Comment: I know its empty but i would like to see the pattern.. Well, try by adding Model name before field name as documentation suggested like `echo $this->Form->input('Photo.imgpath', array('type' => 'hidden'));`

Comment: I mean even to see a pattern it does not print anything :( and I did as suggested but still it doesn't work. Is it correct the way I have put it in model? `'dir' => 'imgpath'`

Comment: Your code if fine now. Well, your debug mode set to which? It might be a issue of model cache...

Comment: Its working fine here... I really don't know whats happening there without looking all of your code... Final tips, truncate your photos table and empty your model and persistent folder under app/tmp/Cache. If its not work, then I have nothing to do...

Comment: how can I upload file via ajax using this plugin?